# windows 10 reset wrongly erased all of my files

Tags: windows, reset

My PC is running Windows 10.  It wouldn't start and I selected to RESET AND KEEP MY FILES.  After the reset, only the "Documents OneDrive" folder was kept.  I had literally only 1 useless file saved in the OneDrive Documents folder.  The "Documents This PC" was not kept!!  The "Downloads This PC" was kept, but not the Documents.  I had more than 100 gigabytes of business and personal files saved to "My Documents" on "This PC." Including a work project I had just completed and saved, literally as the last action before the PC crashed.

Comment: I found them, nevermind

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  That being said, it might be nice if you actually devoted the time to tell us *where* you found them.  That would help the **next** person who inadvertently makes the same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

After an upgrade you should find your old files here:

> C:\Windows.old

[More info here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/recover-personal-files-from-the-windowsold-folder/755e0ea3-b16f-4d5d-89b5-abecfbf68300)